# Android Studio 1.1.0 import R class does not import

Tags: java, android, class

I've searched extensively for the answer but most answers are outdated and all the rest haven't worked.

I am new to Android studio and am working in it for a project. However, when I put in

`import com.example.greenguff.camtest.R;`

It tells me that it is unused and everything that references R gets marked with an error. I have also tried

`import android.R;`

from an answer. No dice on that either. I've messed around in my compiler settings. I've cleaned and rebuilt the project numerous times. I'm at my wit's end. Up-to-date help would be appreciated!

Comment: Firstly you should know the package name of the resource that you use. Make sure your project name space is `com.example.greenguff.camtest` or it won't work. Secondly, make sure that R file is generated.

Comment: You don't need to import R.java, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error/3259974#3259974

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung The package name is correct.

Comment: @DanielNugent That question is old and commenting out the import does nothing to fix the lines that use R. Ex:

`btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start);`

Comment: Have you tried to build from command line see exactly what the problem is? gradle clean installDebug --info (or whatever variants you have).

Comment: Try **File>Invalidate Caches/ Restart>Invalidate and Restart**.

Answer (score -1):

Try to Re-build your app and clean it.